# How To Disable CSRF Protection For All Routes In Laravel5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, csrf

Is there any way in Laravel 5.2 to disable csrf protection for all routes without using VerifyCsrfToken middelware and $except[] array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove or comment out this line in `app\Http\Kernel.php`:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

Answer (score 10):

In your `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken` class add the following code:

```
protected $except = [
    '*',
];
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris)

Comment: protected $except = [
    'mobile/*',
    'news/articles',
];